# Query to delete last two rows as one row is duplicate in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
+-------+--------+
| EMPID | SALARY |
+-------+--------+
|     1 |    100 |
|     2 |    200 |
|     3 |    300 |
|     4 |    400 |
|     4 |    400 |
|     5 |    500 |
+-------+--------+
```

Help me to find out the query which deletes last two rows. I have already tried using where condition but last three rows are being deleted as (4,400) is a duplicate.

Comment: Do u want to delete all  `duplicate` entries?

Comment: your title says Sql Server, but Tag says MYSQL which is ture?

Comment: What do you want exactly? It is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can set limit for that

```
DELETE `employee`  ORDER BY `EMPID` DESC LIMIT 2
```

AS you can add your where clause like. WHERE EMPID = '104', EMPID = '105'

Comment: I hope OP is using `Sql Server`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this query:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT [EMPID], [SALARY],
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [EMPID], [SALARY] ORDER BY (SELECT 0))
   FROM dbo.myTable
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

Comment: @MM93:- But I dint changed anything? Anyways the syntax and the query  was working from start, check the demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cc903/2 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If you want to all the duplicate records, this will delete a employee if he has duplicate salary since you said you want to delete two records.

```
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT *,
                cnt= Count(1)OVER(PARTITION BY EMPID
                         ORDER BY (select null))
         FROM   yourTable)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE  cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to delete the last 2 rows as stated (one of which is duplicate), this should work.

**Query**

```
;WITH D as (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EMPID DESC) as rn,EMPID, SALARY
FROM YourTable
)
DELETE FROM D
WHERE rn <= 2;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0cdd72/4)